# Do I realy need to one-hot the gender?

Tags: one-hot-encoding

I know the advantange of one-hot method in many categories, but if the question only for two category(like gender,only male and female),'the distance of 1 to 0' is same to 'the distance of 0 to 1'.In this case, do we really need a one-hot coding?
PS:My English is not good,Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how the gender is represented in the input data: if it's already as 0 and 1, then there's no need to do anything obviously. However if it's as strings like "Male" and "Female", then you must encode it since the features have to be numerical.

Also note that sometimes you might have more than two categories even for gender, e.g. "non-binary" or "prefer not to say".